# AngularJS - Adding Configuration File to Project

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

config.properties

```
foo="fooTest"
bar="barTest"
```

configGrabber.java

```
//Not going to paste all the code
//It successfully returns the JSON containing the config.properties file
//path to this is /resources
```

load-config.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
    angular.module('configService', [])
        .service('configFac', function ($http) {
            var data;
            $http.get('../api/resources').then(function (response) {
                data = response.data;
            });
        });
}());
```

app.js

```
(function () {
     'use strict';

  angular.module('app', ['configService'])
    .controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, configService, $q) {
        var data;
        $q.all([configService]).then(function (response) {
            data = response[0];
        });
        $scope.configResources = data;
   });
}());
```

index.html

```
...
<div>{{configResources.foo}}</div>
<div>{{configResources.bar}}</div>
...
```

So I'm trying to add a configuration file in this project so the user can easily customize it. The JSON file is getting to load-config.js fine, but the data isn't transferring over to the controller, is there any errors or flaws you can find in this code?

Comment: You're not calling the service correctly from the looks of it. You need to return it

Comment: How would the code look for that?

Answer (score 0):

If the service exists simply for this reason and therefore won't need any more functions it can just look like this:

```
.service('configFac', function ($http) {
    return $http.get('../api/resources')
        .then(function success(response) {
            console.log('Success: '+JSON.stringify(response));
            return response;
        }, function error(error) {
            console.log('Error: '+JSON.stringify(error));
            return error;
    });
};
```

Comment: Trying this now, just had to fix some jslint errors